# How to write GIF image from url to documents directory

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a gif image [url](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif) and want to download it to the documents directory, for this I have tried using

```
if let gifImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) {
    try gifImageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
}
```

and also

```
if let jpegImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0) {
    try jpegImageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
}
```

But this image is saving as a single png/jpg image and not as animated gif

Any solution for this?

Comment: You should not use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Just save the data. like Baig's answer

Comment: this worked just writing by downloaded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with you filename, Try this:

```
//The URL to Save
let yourURL = NSURL(string: "http://somewebsite.com/somefile.gif")
//Create a URL request
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: yourURL!)
//get the data
let theData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

//Get the local docs directory and append your local filename.
var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last as? NSURL

docURL = docURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myFileName.gif")

//Lastly, write your file to the disk.
theData?.writeToURL(docURL!, atomically: true)
```

Comment: may I know whats the use of option atomically while writing

Comment: atomically: true means, the data is written to a backup file, and then—assuming no errors occur—the backup file is renamed to the name specified by path; otherwise, the data is written directly to path.

Answer (score 0):

check you should download

```
func download() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"),
                let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url)
            {
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
                let filePath="\(documentsPath)/tempFile.gif";
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                    }) { completed, error in
                        if completed {
                            print("photo is saved!")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the use of ```PHPhotoLibrary```

Comment: import Photos
to save in library